# New XCODE 6.3 Updated: Apr 8, 2015 Build: 6D570 buggy with Unit Tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

XCODE Updated: Apr 8, 2015
Build: 6D570

After working with the latest beta-Version quite successfully I now updated to the new release and I am surprised how buggy it seems to be.
Indexing forever,
Single Unit tests cannot be executed because the "func testXXX" line is not recognized as a test and is missing the button to perform this tests.

Is there a workaround? I need to execute single tests because all my tests take 1-2 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the whole test suit at least once (using ⌘U OR Product >> Test) you can then right click on individual tests and select "Text XXX" to run that single test again... But each time you add a new test you have to run them all again to discover them...

From the Xcode 6.3 release notes:

> Swift tests are not automatically discovered in this release of Xcode.
>   Test annotations in the source editor sidebar will not appear, and the
>   test navigator and the table of tests in the Test action of the scheme
>   sheet will be empty. You can run Swift tests by selecting Product >
>   Test. Once tests have been run, they appear in the test navigator and
>   the scheme sheet. The following limitations apply:
>
> Tests discovered through execution in this manner provide limited
>   interaction in the test navigator. For example, Run buttons do not
>   appear and clicking on a test in the navigator does not jump to the
>   source code except in the case of a test error. Run buttons and test
>   success/fail indicators will not appear in the source editor.
>   (20373533)

Comment: Is that a bug or a feature? :-(

Comment: I hadn't read the release notes when I found this, and I'd been scratching my head for an hour. I didn't even suspect that they could have rolled back the functionality. Oh well. Thanks for this answer. Upvoted. 

@TimmKent I'm sure there are fancier workarounds, but for now I've wrapped the body of each test in a conditional: if runTests { ... }. runTests is just a strong bool that I flip to false whenever my tests disappear from the sidebar, and then I run all tests again to have them reappear in the UI. Then I set runTests to true, and proceed with my testing.